# How to select the earliest date and data that corresponds to it

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a very simple question that's kicking my ass.

```
CUSTNMBR   |  first_date |  SOPNUMBE
----------------------------------------
3344771005 |  2012-05-03 |  334471961748         
3344771005 |  2012-04-04 |  334476873726
```

In the above table i want to return the earliest date along with the `custnumbr` and `sopnumbe` so it'll look like this

```
3344771005 |  2012-04-04 |  334476873726
```

I used this

```
Select a.CUSTNMBR, min(a.Tax_Date) as first_date, a.SOPNUMBE
from SOP30200 as a
where a.CUSTNMBR = '3344771005'
Group by a.CUSTNMBR, a.SOPNUMBE
```

but it returns all variables and if I knock off the `a.sopnumbe` in group it errors out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select top 1 a.CUSTNMBR, a.Tax_Date as first_date, a.SOPNUMBE 
from SOP30200 as a 
where a.CUSTNMBR = '3344771005' 
order by a.Tax_Date asc
```

Comment: Yes, based on the question no group by was needed, just a sort by and the top 1 to only return the topmost row.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select TOP 1 a.CUSTNMBR, min(a.Tax_Date)as first_date, a.SOPNUMBE
from SOP30200 as a
where a.CUSTNMBR = '3344771005'
Group by a.CUSTNMBR, a.SOPNUMBE'
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```